# using jQuery to determine current span css content: url(.../...) value

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a span tag that is assigned css classes via a stylesheet depending on whether it is clicked it changes values. The css image is done via content as shown below:

ie. here is part of the css:

```
.nav li > a > span:after {
font-size: 19px;
content: url(../images/expand.gif);
}
.nav li.open > a > span:after {
content: url(../images/collapse.gif);
}
```

The span does not have an id but is within a hyperlink tag that does have a unique id.
I was able to assign a variable via jQuery to each specific span tag. The code I will paste below gives me the link value of the hyperlink parent node but what I actually need is the current value of the content url assigned in the css.

Here is an example of the php & jQuery from the code I am working on:

```
$content = '
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {';

foreach ($catchClass as $id)
{
    $content .= '
    var $span = $("#' . $id['id'] . ' span");
    var check = $span.after("eq")[0].parentNode;
    // alert("test: " + check);
    if (check === "../images/collapse.gif") {
        $span.attr("style", "font-size: 19px; content: url(../images/collapsex.gif);");         
    }
    elseif (check === "../images/expand.gif") {
        $span.attr("style", "font-size: 19px; content: url(../images/expandx.gif);");           
    }
    ';

}
$content .= '   
});
</script>';
```

The alert is just so I can see when I get the proper value I am looking for. The line containing this: var check = $span.after("eq")[0].parentNode; ... is what I need to change to get the content url value I am looking for. $catchClass holds the array of hyperlink id's displayed on the page. I have been searching through all kinds of threads on this forum for the answer but to no avail. Would someone be able to help me with this dilemma?

Thank you.

Comment: var check = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("a#' . $id['id'] . ' > span"), ":after").getPropertyValue("content");I actually figured this out myself after a lot of trial and error. The solution is as follows:                                                           .... I can not even press enter in this comment?!?! apologies but this message posting on this forum is very odd and restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Since `:after` pseudo its rendered by CSS, it's not a DOM element, so you have to access it through `getComputedStyle`

```
var check = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('#ELEMENT_ID span'), ':after'
);
if (check['content'] == 'url(../images/collapse.gif)') { ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.. I just figured it out myself prior to your comment. I must say I like this forum but I am not fond of how the message posting is set up. I tried to press enter in my comment to drop down a line to post the code properly and it would not let me because it saves the post when enter is used. This is just for my added comment but it is very awkward.

Comment: But the way you figured out is like this one, or have you found another way?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment now!

Comment: Ok.. I see there is answer and comment.. I am not used to this forum as of yet.. Thank you for the answer and it is the same as what I figured only it doesn't seem to work the same in all browsers. Also this only retrieves the value of the first css content prior to anything being clicked. I need it to gather the value even when it has been changed.